# How to take time as a input from user in the form HHMM and then run a function at that time

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am writing a code where the user will be asked for time in the form of HHMM multiple times using a loop and then this time will be appended to a list. Now I want a function to be executed at the various times in that list provided by the user.

Comment: relative time or static time?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: 0001 , in relative terms it means after 1 minute a function. In static term , function runs at 00:01 AM

Comment: Are the times always on the current day?

Comment: yes, the time is of the same day

Comment: You can probably run a loop, check if the current time is in the list of times; then sleep for one minute or less. But it is hard to tell the right thing without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime` to perform the necessary calculations.

In this example, the target time is parsed using `strptime` but the date is not supplied so the time part is correct but the date part is wrong.  The first three fields (year, month, day) are then replaced with today's date to produce a datetime object that correctly represents the target time.  The current time can then be subtracted to give a `timedelta` object that represents the amount of time that needs to be waited until the task can be run.

```
import time
import datetime


def hello():
    print("hello")


def run_at_times(func, times):

    today = datetime.date.today()
    
    for hhmm in sorted(times):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(hhmm, "%H%M")
        when = datetime.datetime(*today.timetuple()[:3],
                                 *dt.timetuple()[3:6])

        wait_time = (when - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()

        if wait_time < 0:
            print(f'Time {when} has already passed')
        else:
            print(f'Waiting {wait_time} seconds until {when}')
            time.sleep(wait_time)
            func()


run_at_times(hello, ["1041", "1203", "1420"])
```